# Tuples in Scala not working as expected

Tags: scala, maps, tuples

Can you please help me in understanding the behaviour

```
  //Creating a tuple
  val myTuple = ("Sudipta","Deb","Switzerland",1234)
                                                  //> myTuple  : (String, String, String, Int) = (Sudipta,Deb,Switzerland,1234)
  myTuple._2                                      //> res0: String = Deb
  myTuple._4                                      //> res1: Int = 1234
  val (first, second, third, fourth) = myTuple    //> first  : String = Sudipta
                                                  //| second  : String = Deb
                                                  //| third  : String = Switzerland
                                                  //| fourth  : Int = 1234
  //val (first1, second1, _) = myTuple
```

Now last line is giving me the error:

```
constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;  found   : (T1, T2, T3)  required: (String, String, String, Int)
```

My Question is why it is behaving like this? In the Scala for Impatient Book this is what is written:

```
You can use a _ if you don’t need all components:
val (first, second, _) = t
```

Just for your reference, if you want to see the full code, it is in my GitHub Repository. Link: [Scala Worksheet](https://github.com/suddeb/MyScalaForImpatient/blob/master/ScalaForImpatient/src/com/sudipta/practice/chapter4/practice_2.sc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put one `_` for every unused tuple member.

```
val (first1, second1, _, _) = myTuple
```

Comment: Ok. Got it. So it is not like var args in Java? If I have to put _ for every unused tuple member, then it means I have to know how many elements are there in Tuple, right?

Comment: No its like pattern matching in functional languages. If this is not enough you can replace the tuple with a class and use it's selector functions to access the members. If the data is simple you can create a case class that is very much like a tuple.

Comment: It is exactly a pattern match. Compare `val is = List(1,2,3,4) ; val List(x,y,_*) = is`. So yes, for ordinary TupleN you must know arity N.